# chamar as propriedades de um TableViewCell em um ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewcell

estou tentando criar uma tableview com a cell dinâmica de acordo com o texto dentro dela, e estou querendo somar o tamanha height da label com o tamanho da cell porem quando eu chamo a label no ViewConrtoller ele esta vazio e quando eu chamo no TableViewCell ele me da o tamanho certo, como passar o (label.frame.size.height) do TableViewCell para o viewcontroller sem perde seu valor.

Comment: Tenta com isso.
<pre>
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
</pre>

Comment: ja estou usando esse metodo porem não consigo passar o valor da label que esta em meu TableViewCell para o viewcontroller

Comment: como vc calcula o tamanho da celular?

Comment: `CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296, FLT_MAX);
    
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [self.descriptin.text sizeWithFont:self.label.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:self.label.lineBreakMode];
    
    CGRect newFrame = self.label.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    self.label.frame = newFrame;
`

Comment: Dynamic Table View Cell Height and Auto Layout - http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele - você sempre pode comentar em suas próprias publicações e quando tiver [pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes você poderá [comentar sobre qualquer publicação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Publique o código que você fez para que possamos te ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você pode tentar assim no cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    cell.Label-em-questao.tag = 789;
    [self sendCELL:cell];
```

depois você recupera os dados em:

```
- (void)sendCELL:(UITableViewCell *)sender {
    CGRect tag = [(UILabel*)[(UITableViewCell *)sender.superview viewWithTag:789]frame];
    int width = tag.size.width;
    NSLog(@"%d", width);
}
```